# standalone jar lags

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

when i'm running my project in eclipse, it works fine, when i export it as standalone jar it lags. i'm using the same vmargs, tried 3 different export settings in eclipse, nothing seems to help

Comment: Do you mean that the applicaton as a whole runs slower, or is it just slower starting up?

Comment: the app is a game and it doesn't run fluently like in eclipse, it stops for part of a second or more and general framerate is less

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a JVM warmup or garbage collection issue.

I would take another look at the way that you are launching the game / application from the standalone JAR.

- check that you are running with Java 6.0
- experiment with the -client and -server policies
- experiment with giving it a larger initial heap (-Xms)
- experiment with using the CMS garbage collector.

Comment: -XX:PermSize=256m -Xms512m -Xmx512m

Comment: -XX:PermSize=756m -Xms756m -Xmx756m or -XX:PermSize=256m -Xms1328m -Xmx1328m or -XX:PermSize=1024m -Xms512m -Xmx512m          but get no visible effect. eclipse just using  the default settings plus this vargs. i have no clue about garbage collection settings

Comment: @jeff, as Stephen said, you should also verify that your standalone JAR is being run with the same Java version as what it was running in under Eclipse.

Comment: Agree, check you are running with the latest Java 6.